# Why does my rack app occasionally load weird without the layout after I save a file in it?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack, ramaze

I'm using the Ramaze framework for my rack app, and whenever I save a file in my app on my computer or use git push to give the server the newest files, for Heroku and refresh the page, I'm greeted with the page without the layout file. Strangely it doesn't happen on my computer if I wait before saving the page, but will if I dom't wait.

[image: bad]
[image: bad 2]

I must refresh again to get this.
[image: good]
[image: good 2]

It doesn't happen on Dotcloud, Cloud Foundry or Openshift. I cannot upgrade to the latest version of Ramaze as it's not backwards compatible, so I'd have to make more changes. I'm using Rack version `1.4.2` and Ramaze version `2012.04.14`

Comment: When you get the unstyled page, see what css is being loaded. It should be something like app.css?382482.  Compare that with the second request. I think what is happening is the static asset is being replaced and you are loading it before the app reloads.

Comment: There's no css being loaded. Here's the html source code of the page being rendered. https://gist.github.com/desbest/f82e060ac966f5a799d8